# Can the android TV emulator in android studio recieve casts?

Tags: android-studio, google-cast

I am currently trying to implement the **Cast SDK** into my app and I am running into a few issues the biggest one of them being that I do not own a **Chromecast**, is there a way to test my code to make sure it casts correctly without owning an **Android TV** or a **Chromecast**?

Does the **Android TV emulator** in **Android Studio** support cast reception?

What are the alternatives here?

Answer (score 0):

No, the emulator is not going to work for testing the cast functionality.

Comment: how to test cast functionality without physical android tv?